# Why does extend method on class an instance works differently with inheritance?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

```
module B
  def a
    print 'B'
    super
  end
end

class A
  extend B

  def a
    print "A"
  end

  def self.a
    print "A"
  end
end

a = A.new

a.extend B
puts a.a # => BA
puts A.a # => A
```

Why does Kernel#extend method work differently for class objects and class instance object? It looks like it prepends module in the chain of inheritance if we extend an instance, but puts the module above the class if we extend a class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first introduce a few concepts.

First, defining a class method using `def self.a` is the same as defining a method on the class' singleton class:

```
class C
  def self.a; end

  class << self
    def b; end
  end
end

C.method(:a) # => #<Method: C.a>
C.method(:b) # => #<Method: C.b>
```

Further, a method on an object is an instance method on that objects singleton class:

```
C.singleton_class.instance_method(:a) # => #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:C>#a>
C.singleton_class.instance_method(:b) # => #<UnboundMethod: #<Class:C>#b>
```

If you look at how we defined `#b` above, you see that we did not prefix it with `self`, thus this just an instance method.

Next, `#extend` is the same as `#include` on the singleton class:

```
module M; end

class C1
  extend M
end

class C2
  class << self
    include M
  end
end

C1.ancestors # => [#<Class:C2>, M, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
C2.ancestors # => [#<Class:C1>, M, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Notice how `M` is now part of the ancestors of `C1` and `C2` in the same way.

The inclusion of (or extension with) `M` could also have been achieved as follows:

```
C1.extend M
C2.singleton_class.include M
```

Lastly, note what happens to the ancestors when we `#include` a module:

```
module M1; end
module M2; end
class C; end

C.include M1
C.ancestors # => [C, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

C.include M2
C.ancestors # => [C, M2, M1, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Every `#include` resulted in the module being inserted after the receiver (`C` in this case) in the ancestor chain.

Now let's look at your definitions (omitting the bodies):

```
module B; end

class A
  extend B
end
```

Remember, `#extend` is the same as `#include` on the `#singleton_class`. Thus, we can rewrite it as follows:

```
module B; end
class A; end
A.singleton_class.include B
```

The ancestors of the singleton class now have `B` after the first item, which is the singleton class of `A` where class methods are defined (remember, class methods are thus just instance methods on the singleton class of the class in question):

```
A.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:A>, B, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Moving on to the second part of your code:

```
a = A.new
a.extend B
```

Rewriting it using `#include`:

```
a = A.new
a.singleton_class.include B
```

Let's check the ancestors:

```
a.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:#<A:0x00007f83e714be88>>, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Again, the `#include` placed the module after the first element in the ancestor chain, resulting in `B` before `A`.

This means that when sending `#a` to `a` (i.e. `a.a`), it will look for the first ancestor that responds to `#a`, which is `B` in this case. `B` will then call `super`, which will continue along the ancestor chain where it finds `A` that responds to `#a`.

Now for `A.a`, it will be different. Remember the ancestors of `A`'s singleton class:

```
A.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:A>, B, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Notice how `B` comes after `#<Class:A>`. `#<Class:A>` already responds to `#a`, which is the class method on `A`. Because that method doesn't call `super`, `B#a` will never be invoked. Hence, you don't get the same output.

If you want to have `B` before `#<Class:A>`, you'd have to prepend B to `A`'s singleton class. `#prepend` inserts an object at the very beginning of the ancestor chain unlike `#include`, which inserts it after the first item (you have to remove the `extend B` in your code for this to work otherwise nothing happens if `B` is already an ancestor):

```
A.singleton_class.prepend B
A.singleton_class.ancestors # => [B, #<Class:A>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Invoking `A.a` will now produce the same as `a.a`, namely print `BA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
A.singleton_class.ancestors
   #=> [#<Class:A>, B, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module,
   #    Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
A.method(:a).owner
   #=> #<Class:A>
```

so we should not be surprised that

```
A.a
```

prints `"A"`, not `"B"`.

Now let's consider extending `B` on an instance of `A`:

```
aa = A.new
aa.extend B

aas = aa.singleton_class
  #=> #<Class:#<A:0x00005b19441bf6a8>> 
aas.methods.include?(:a)
  #=> true
aa.method(:a).owner
  #=> B 
aas.superclass
  #=> A
m = aa.method(:a).super_method
  #=> #<Method: A#a> 
m.owner
  #=> A
```

Therefore,

```
aa.a
BA
```

first invokes the method `a` defined on `aa`'s singleton class, which prints the letter `"B"`, then it invokes it's superclass, `A`, to execute `A.a`, that method being `A::a`, causing it to print `"A"`.